# Jest + React Native, how to configure iOS and Android unit testing from scratch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, metro-bundler

I have a Lerna monorepository with a Web application and a module:

```sh
.
├── apps
│   └── id-check-app            <# Web application (create-react-app)
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   └── id-check                <# Module made with react-native-web
├── tsconfig.json                # and compatible with react-native
└── yarn.lock
```

The `id-check` module within `packages` is made with `react-native-web`, aliased on `react-native` imports.

So far, we are able to test for the Web but if we use custom version of our components for **iOS or Android, then we are not able to test their `react-native` versions**.

I may try to bootstrap a fresh react native application in the `apps` directory for being able to test them. (Note: we do not use expo)

How can I configure React Native and Jest to be able to test components for iOS and Android our components using the real `react-native` package?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? :)

Comment: I did, using `--config` option of jest and by creating a web configuration using the `react-native-web` preset.